# negative prediction values in h2o package in r

Tags: r, neural-network, regression, prediction, h2o

i am currently setting up a neural network in R to predict demand forecasts. i use the h20-package with a regression model because i would like to forecast demands based on historical data.
Currently the prototype is there and i receive some predictions, but some of the predicted values are negative and i dont know why.
Could you guys help me with that?

**context**: 
I have 2 tables with each several hundret columns. The values are aggregated per week.
The first table contains configurations.
The second table shows the demand that results from these configurations

**The structure of my code**:

- load data
- add 1 column of demand table to configurations (that i want to predict and train the neural network with)
- feature scaling (except last column)
- train neural network
- predict last column with test data

the code for my model:

```
model = h2o.deeplearning(y = [column to predict],
                           training_frame = as.h2o(training_data),
                           activation = 'Rectifier',
                           hidden = c(100,100),
                           epochs = 50,
                           train_samples_per_iteration = -2)
```

My problem now is my predictions contain negative values even though i use the Rectifier activation function.
Where is my mistake?

If u need any further information, let me know. I am a rooky in here :)

Thanks already for your help.

Comment: and here still an excerpt of my test data:
**Configurations table**
CW  VarA VarB VarC ...
1       300   233    100
2       267   100    120
3       100   177    150
...

**demands table**
CW VarA VarB VarD ...
1       150    200   70
2       100      60   40
3         80    130   66
...

Answer (score 0):

The predictions get re-scaled back to the scale of the original response column.  If the range of your response column includes 0 (or close to 0), it's possible that you will get negative predictions.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Is it possible to adjust the input values (e.g. add a certain value to all values) and do the calculations with these numbers.

Comment: Do you mean adjust the *feature* input values or the *response* input values?  If response, then check out the `offset_column` parameter: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/offset_column.html

Comment: what if also some feature input values are 0 or close to 0? is this `offset_column` or sth similar also available for that?

Comment: The features are automatically scaled and normalized inside the `h2o.deeplearning()` function, so the scale of the original values doesn't matter.